# Constrain return type of a function that accepts Either

Tags: scala, casting, either

I am trying to make a function like this:

```
 def foo(x: Either[String, Int]) = x match {
   case Left(s) => Left("foo:" + s)
   case Right(n) => Right(n+1)
 }
```

This works, but I am looking for a way to assure the caller, that the result will always be of the same type as input - if input is Left, you get Left back, if it was Right, you get Right.

Can someone think of a neat trick I could use to do that?

I know, I can do this:

```
 def foo[T <: Either[String, Int]](x: T): T = (x match {
   case Left(s) => Left("foo:" + s)
   case Right(n) => Right(n+1)
 }).asInstanceOf[T]
```

... but the cast in the end is ugly :(
This declaration is going to be an abstract member of a base trait, that several implementation "plugins" will need to override, and I don't want to make all of them to have to do this type-casting thing.

I could also make two separate functions `fooString`, and `fooInt` ... but that is something I'd like to avoid, because of some considerations, specific to the particular api I am working on.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you are not restricted to using Either, you can use type classes -

```
sealed trait Transformer[A] {
 def transform(n: A): A
}
object Transformer {
 implicit object IntTransformer extends Transformer[Int] { def transform(n: Int) = n + 1 }
 implicit object StringTransformer extends Transformer[String] { def transform(s: String) = "foo:" + s }
}

def foo[A: Transformer](x: A)(implicit transformer: Transformer[A]) = transformer.transform(x)
```

Comment: If you do want to deal specifically with `Either`, you can also create implicit `Transformer[Left/Right/Either[String, Int]]` (`Either` would pattern-match by type).

Answer (score 1):

This signature doesn't actually say what you want it to say:

```
val x = Left("a")
val y = foo[x.type](x)
```

`y`'s type is `x.type` and so it must be the same instance, which it isn't. It follows that you need to change the signature if you want to avoid a cast. One approach (not tested):

```
trait LowPriorityFooImplicits { _: FooImplicits =>
  implicit def eitherFoo(x: Either[String, Int]): Foo[Either[String, Int]] = new Foo(x) {
    def foo() = x match {
      case y: Left[String, Int] => y.foo()
      case z: Right[String, Int] => z.foo()
  }
}

trait FooImplicits extends LowPriorityFooImplicits {
  sealed trait Foo[A <: Either[String, Int]](x: A) {
    def foo(): A
  }

  implicit def leftFoo(x: Left[String, Int]): Foo[Left[String, Int]] = new Foo(x) {
    def foo() = Left(fooString(x.value))
  }
  implicit def rightFoo ...

  // x will be implicitly converted from a subtype of Either[String, Int]
  def foo[A](x: Foo[A]): T = x.foo()

  protected def fooString(s: String) = "foo:" + s
  protected def fooInt(n: Int) = n + 1
}
```

(It still has `fooString` and `fooInt`, but not in the public API.)